# The is_sorted() function does not work correctly in my code

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code, in which a number is input, and then an array of that number of values, for example:

```
6
2
4
7
7
9
3
```

All of them being in an index of the array, like this:

```
2-----0
4-----1
7-----2
7-----3
9-----4
3-----5
```

In this code, I want to find if all the elements from index 3 to the end of the array are sorted or not, ie if `7 9 3` is sorted, using the `is_sorted()` function, like this:

```cpp
is_sorted(v+2+1, v+n-2-1)
```

So, this would be like `is_sorted(0+2+1, 0+6-2-1)` or `is_sorted(3, 3)`.  Basically, checking if the array `7 9 3` is sorted, which is obviously not true, but my code reports 1 instead of 0.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;

    cin >> n;
    int v[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        v[i] = a;
    }

    cout << is_sorted(v+2+1, v+n-2-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
int n;
int v[n];
```

is undefined behavior (assuming VLAs were part of C++, which they aren't).

Please compile your code with warnings.

Comment: How should i fix it

Answer (score 0):

is_sorted takes a beginning and end iterator, so when you call `is_sorted(v+3, v+3)` you're checking from the 3rd element to the 3rd element (exclusive) -- zero elements in total.  If you want to check to the end of the array the second argument should be the end of the array -- `v+n`

Also, you should ***never*** include anything in the bits directory directly -- that is part of the internal implementation of the standard library and will likely change and break in any other version of the compiler or library.